# How to collect data from user using a form from an email using SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I want to create a feature in SharePoint 2010. Note: I have no experience with SharePoint.

- User creates an item in a list
- Selected users from the item will get notified in an email
- Email should have an attachment form where they enter some value and click on submit
- Data submitted by the users should be reflected to the list

Comment: Why not simply link to the edit form in the email? This seems overly complex for little gain in UX when there's an OOTB solution available.

Comment: Unless you need to support external users then sending something as attachment in the e-mail defeats the purpose of Sharepoint - to store centrally and share. So what you need to do is to 1. Create workflow with Sharepoint Designer. It should autostart on the item creation. In the workflow logic you need read the CurrentItem id and create link with url of the Edit.aspx for the item. Then send it to users. Couple of things to watch out in that case. You would have to enable checking/out functionality on the item, and versioning so you could differentiate between the different answers.

Comment: check in/out and versioning is important is necessary as well so one user won't overwrite each other's answer.